# XMLHttpRequest responseText is empty

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I have read much on this site, but I can't solve my problem! :( 
It must be very easy but it does not work!

The problem is `http.responseText` is empty.

I'm using the webspace on http://www.000webhost.com

Is it posible to get a String with the Sourcecode of `www.google.de`?

Thanks for any help!

```
<html> 
<title>Test Site</title>
<body>
<h1>My Example</h1>
<script type="text/javascript">

var http = new XMLHttpRequest();

http.open("GET", 'https://www.google.de', true);
http.send(null);

http.onreadystatechange = function() {
    alert(http.responseText);
}

alert("The end is reached");
</script> 


<b>Here is some more HTML</b> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can't download other people's stuff with ajax, unless they turn on CORS to allow it.

Comment: Same Origin Policy; https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript

Comment: If you are trying to make a request to a different domain the request returned empty ("Access-Control-Allow-Origin")

Comment: Look at your JavaScript console. Read the error messages you get.

Comment: To add to @Quentin, errors like these come from the security errors in your console. If you have these turned off or hidden, you will not see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its not possible with ajax because of same origin policy , but to solve your problem you can use server side programming like PHP or Nodejs. basically PHP will be available in web hostings.

create getGoogle.php

```
 <?php 
    // create curl resource 
    $ch = curl_init(); 

    // set url 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "www.google.de"); 

    //return the transfer as a string 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

    // $output contains the output string 
    $output = curl_exec($ch); 

    // close curl resource to free up system resources 
    curl_close($ch);  

    echo $output;    
  ?>
```

use your javascript as below

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

  var http = new XMLHttpRequest();

   http.open("GET", 'getGoogle.php', true);
   http.send(null);

   http.onreadystatechange = function() {
        alert(http.responseText);
   }

   alert("The end is reached");
   </script>
```

Hope this solves your problem. Cheers

Comment: I tried it with cURL! Google is only an example. I can't use cURL couse I have to post Username and Passwort and it will work only with CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION=true! But the webhoster have safemode enabeld so cURL is'nt an option! :( I thout maybe I can solve it with Javascript. I Think CORS is not allowed so is there a way to get the information from an other Domain? Belive me I'm asking googel since 3 days.

Comment: hey I got the solution for the curl error. use this code http://pastie.org/7646116  which has the function called "curl_exec_follow" , you have to use this function instead of curl_exec (replace curl_exec with curl_exec_follow)

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your help! There is no Error form the Webhost but i recied only "Array" as String and not the HTML Surcecode from the site. :( Whats wrong? '$result = curl_exec_follow($ch);'

Comment: I could not solve my problem, but its the right answer of my Question! So Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Making client side http requests is limited by the browser to only allowing requests from the same server that supplied the original page. This is what is being referred to as the Same Origin Policy.

As mentioned by others, this is normally done by requesting the URL in your server side code.